# how to create a enum with compute value when case and value is 1 vs 1 correlation in swift?

Tags: swift

I would like to create one enum that the case name present the value like `Apple.good == "I am good" , Apple.bad == "I am bad"` It seems like code 2 works but can I use something without `value` variable?

Code 1

```
enum Apple {
    case good
    case bad
}
let a = Apple.good // I am good
print(a)
```

Code 2

```
enum Apple {
    case good
    case bad
    var value: String {
        switch self {
        case .good: return "I am good"
        case .bad: return "I am bad"
        }
    }
}
let a = Apple.good.value // I am good
print(a)
```

Answer (score 2):

> …but can I use something without value variable?

Yes, you can assign the *raw value* to the cases and adopt `CustomStringConvertible`.

When you print the cases the `description` property is called which returns the raw value

```
enum Apple : String, CustomStringConvertible {
    case good = "I am good"
    case bad = "I am bad"
    
    var description : String { rawValue }
}
let a = Apple.good // I am good
print(a)
```

Or still shorter

```
enum Apple : String, CustomStringConvertible {
    case good, bad
    
    var description : String { "I am " + rawValue }
}
let a = Apple.good // I am good
print(a)
```

**Nevertheless your approach *Code 2* is another correct way.**

Comment: But I would emphasize that there was absolutely nothing wrong with the OP's original approach.

Comment: This has the downside of not being localizable. Though the 2nd option could be made localizable with some changes (more closely matching the OP's original "code 2").